# Element positioning - reference to a higher component

Tags: angular, css

I've some Angular application with similar structure as below, and I would know, is it possible to position `divWhichShouldBeInCenterOf-appMainComponent` in the center of `appMainComponent` using css (at the end of the post)?

```
appMainComponent
|
 -- internalComponent
    |
    --div
       |
       --component
        |
        --divWhichShouldBeInCenterOf-appMainComponent
```

CSS

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Comment: It depends really on what CSS rules you have on the other parent elements, and what other CSS rules you have on `divWhichShouldBeInCenterOf`. Are you able to create a basic StackBlitz demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

this CSS centers the element and removes it from the page flow.
it will be in the center of the nearest positioned parent

which means that if any element between divWhichShouldBeInCenterOf-appMainComponent and appMainComponent that has position other than static, it will be used as a reference to be centered against.